# Is it possible to run a "Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Hyper-V Virtual Machine" on Windows 7x64 Pro machine?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

Specifically, I want to run this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

---

This download contains a three Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Hyper-V Virtual Machine set for evaluating and demonstrating Office 2010, SharePoint 2010 and Project Server 2010.

---

System requirements
Supported operating systems: **Windows Server 2008 R2**

Additionally you will need:

•Windows Server 2008 R2 (SP1 recommended) with the Hyper-V role enabled.
•Drive Formatting: NTFS
•Processor: Intel VT or AMD-V capable
•RAM: 8 GB or more recommended
•Hard disk space required for install: 100 GB

### -------------------------

---

So, the above text *seems* to indicate that you need a physical Windows 2008 Server (r2) server running, but from the googling I've done on the subject I've yet to come across a discussion that definitively answers the question.  Many posts I've read seem to indicate it might be possible to run it on Windows 7 using one of the following:  VirtualBox, Windows Virtual PC, VMWare but I'm not entirely sure.

### EDIT

This looks like an ideal way to do it?
Windows 7 and the magic of Boot to VHD
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx

Comment: Not sure why this would be downvoted.  Perhaps because I gave a specific example which adds specific context and clarity to the question rather than leaving it more vague?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a clustered Hyper-V setup within VMWware Workstation on my windows 7 laptop from scratch. I would assume you could run the demo environment as well.

I will say, performance is generally pretty terrible when running nested virtualization solutions but it does work. Load up on RAM before even thinking about trying to run something like this.

Comment: So, to clarify: I am running Windows 7x64; so I can install VMWare Workstation and natively open the above linked MS Hyper-V VM?  Or, create a Windows 200 Server r2 VM *within* VMWare, and *then* use that to open the MS Hyper-V VM?

Comment: Install VMWare Workstation, Create a Windows Server guest and install the Hyper-V role, use that guest to import the images from the link.

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws90/doc/workstation-90-release-notes.html#Nested for VMWare's stance on supportability of a nested Hyper-V install in Workstation.

Comment: @Rex Loving this: " For this reason, this capability has been implemented purely to see if we could do it!"

Answer (score 0):

All of the VMs at the link you've supplied are preconfigured for running on top of Hyper-V.  This means that the disk images are in VHD files, the configuration is in the Hyper-V export format and the drivers installed within the VMs are those for Hyper-V.

It is technically possible to unpack them and repackage them for some other virtualization platform, as Hyper-V doesn't run on top of Windows 7, though this strategy may not be within the license for this download.  (I haven't read the license agreement.)

Getting any Hyper-V-targeted VM running on top of some other VMM would require making and equivalent VM configuration and probably driver installation changes.  This is practical for somebody well-versed in manipulating offline Windows images, though not at all straightforward.

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned, it's not that hard to build a Hyper-V lab within newer versions of VMWare (Workstation or vSphere/ESXi). You install a 2008 R2 guest, install the Hyper-V role and then basically treat that guest as a standalone Hyper-V server and use that to import the VHD files or create new Hyper-V guests. As i mentioned, performance is generally not the greatest, but it's useful in lab/testing scenarios.

Comment: Yes, I understood that.  But I was trying to answer tbone's question.  I would expect the performance to be so bad, particularly on a laptop, that another answer was warranted.

Comment: would depend on how much RAM and how fast his hard drives was. With enough RAM and if he is using SSD, you could run a couple hyper-V guests with enough performance to run a small demo. I ran a two-node hyper-v cluster with a freeNAS storage on an 8GB laptop. Was slow and guests took forever to boot, but was mostly workable once things got booted. Had two windows 2008 R2 servers with hyper-v (2GB RAM) and 1 guest in each with 1.5GB RAM) -- edit: of course, one person's view of acceptable performance is not always the same as mine :)

Comment: This sounds like the perfect solution?  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx

Comment: Again, your problem is that those VHDs have an OS image in them set up to run within a Hyper-V VM.  And VHD files are just containers, equivalent to a disk drive.  Just because you can put something on a disk doesn't mean it will boot when you attach it to a computer.  You may need to adjust the contents of the disk to boot it.  The link you listed, tbone, is one that talks about booting a VHD on a physical machine, not a VM.  So instead of adjusting the contents of the virtual disk for a different hypervisor, you'd need to adjust it for your physical machine.

Comment: @JakeOshins - Good point..."those VHDs have an OS image in them set up to run within a Hyper-V VM"; as opposed to Hanselman's example where he is creating a VHD *during the Windows install process*, installing the OS to that VHD, adding it to the Boot Manager, *and then* booting to it....which works prefectly, because it was literally installed on his physical machine.  What happens when I put the VHD I'm downloading onto my machine and boot it..will Windows properly detect hardware changes and install the appropriate drivers?  I think I'll try this and see.

Comment: Actually, Hanselman specifically notes this in the article:  "Second, doing this makes your VHD less portable, because if you move it inside Virtual PC or to another machine, all the devices will freak out and try to reinstall (or maybe just not work) so be aware of that."