# What would happen if I did a "Boot to VHD" to a VHD that was configured to run under Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

Microsoft has a Hyper-V based VM I'm interested in running, however, I don't have access to a Windows Server 2008 machine to try it on, only a Windows 7 Pro x64 machine (Windows 7 does not support Hyper-V).

**This is the VM in question:**

*This download contains three Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Hyper-V Virtual Machine set for evaluating and demonstrating Office 2010, SharePoint 2010 and Project Server 2010.*

**2010 Information Worker Demonstration and Evaluation Virtual Machine (SP1)**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

I came across a *somewhat* relevant article from Scott Hanselman:
**Less Virtual, More Machine - Windows 7 and the magic of Boot to VHD:**
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx

I realize other options are to convert this VM to a VMWare compatible VM or some of the options to run it under VirtualBox.  But instead of those routes, I'm wondering:

***What would happen if I tried to go the "Boot to VHD" route using this Hyper-V VHD?***

Is it possible that during the boot process, Windows would simply notice that hardware had 
changed and adjust accordingly, installing the appropriate drivers and continuing on without a hitch?

Comment: It seems like it would take about as much time to actually test this as it would to write this question.

Comment: @MDMarra - a) Not really  b) Do you think it might be useful information to exist on the internet?  As in, if someone else was to google for this topic and landed here, would the internet be a better place, or a worse place, for the answer being posted here?  Or, should that person "just test it"?

Answer (score 0):

I answered what amounts to the same question when you asked it here:

[Is it possible to run a "Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Hyper-V Virtual Machine" on Windows 7x64 Pro machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/441564/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-hyper-v-virtual-machine-on/441910#comment477820_441910)

It depends entirely on the physical machine.  The more the physical machine differs from a Hyper-V VM, the less likely it is to boot.  You can install drivers for the OS image in the VHD offline to make it more likely to boot, if you like, using offline image management tools like dism.exe.